# PSD matrix differentiation with respect to a scalar

Tags: matrices, derivatives

Suppose I have a symmetric PD matrix $M$ and a function $f(M)$ which is also a symmetric PSD matrix of the same dimensions. How do I find the following expression?

$$\frac{\partial(x^Tf(M)x)}{\partial x^TMx}$$

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\a{\alpha}\def\b{\beta}
\def\t{\theta}\def\l{\lambda}
\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
$Choose two arbitrary scalars $(\a,\b)$ and any vector $w$ such that
$w^Tx\ne 0,\,$ and use them to construct the following two matrices
$$\eqalign{
A &= \a\LR{I-\frac{xw^T}{w^Tx}} \qiq Ax=0 \\
B &= \b\LR{I-\frac{wx^T}{x^Tw}} \qiq x^TB=0\\
}$$
These matrices can be used to perturb $M$ such that
$$\eqalign{
\t \;=\; x^TMx \;=\; x^T\LR{M+A+B}x \\
}$$
Since the value of $\t$ does not *uniquely* determine $M$, it is not possible to find a *function* $\,M=M(\t)$

However, $F=f(M)$ is definitely a function of $M$, therefore it cannot be a function of $\t$ either.

In light of these observations the quantity
$$\eqalign{
\grad{\LR{x^TFx}}{\t} = \grad{\LR{x^TFx}}{\LR{x^TMx}} \\
}$$
does not make mathematical sense.

Or perhaps you are solving a *related rates* problem, wherein a change in $M$ produces a change in both $\LR{x^TFx}{\;\rm and\;}\LR{x^TMx}$ and you are interested in the ratio of these changes.  That is a legitimate problem, but you cannot use this "derivative" to solve it.

Comment: You are correct in saying that I am solving the 'rates' problem. My question is basically trying to capture the following: I know for a fact that M is pertrubed in such a way so that $x^T\tilde{M}x > x^TMx, \forall x$. Now I need to find corresponding to this fact whether the same thing occurs for the function. Since we have symmetry and PD for both numerator and denominator it is basically a eigen-vector and eigen value petrubation problem.

Comment: @DuttaA If the eigenvalues of $M$ are $\mu_k$ then the EVs of $F=f(M)$ are $\phi_k=f(\mu_k)$. The perturbation is such that all of the $\mu_k$ have been increased and the question is: do all of the $\phi_k$ also increase? The answer depends on $f$ and the magnitudes of the EVs. If $f(x)=\exp(x)$ then the answer is an unqualified **yes**. But if it's something like  $f(x)=\sin(x)$ then the answer is **no**. If $f(x)=x^2$ and $\mu_k>{\tt1}$ then **yes**, but if $\mu_k<{\tt1}$ then **no**.  And so on.

Comment: Agree, but how do I find it for a general matrix function.

Comment: @DuttaA Unless $f$ is a monotonically increasing function, I don't think you can draw the desired conclusion.

Comment: $f$ is not a function in a sense you are describing it. It is a matrix to matrix. Monotonic implies matrix to real number.